# sending invitation using linkedin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

Can I use linkedin gem to send invitation by email??

Answer (score 1):

looks like you can not, yet.  From the Readme:

> TODO
>
> Change to json api
>
> Update and correct test suite
>
> Change to Faraday for authentication
>
> Implement Messaging APIs

Answer (score 1):

*config/initializers/linkedin.rb*

```
LinkedIn::Client.class_eval do
  def send_invitation(options)
    path = "/people/~/mailbox"
    message = {
      "recipients" => {
        "values" => [
          {
            "person" => {
              "_path" => "/people/email=#{options[:email]}",
              "first-name" => options[:first_name],
              "last-name" => options[:last_name]
            }
          }]
      },
      "subject" => "Invitation to connect.",
      "body" => options[:body],
      "item-content" => {
        "invitation-request" => {
          "connect-type" => "friend"
        }
      }
    }
    post(path, message.to_json, "Content-Type" => "application/json")
  end
end
```

use like any other gem methods

```
client.send_invitation({:email=>"email", :first_name=>"first name", :last_name=>"last name", :body=>"body"})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LinkedIn::Client.class_eval do
  def send_invitation(options)
    path = "/people/~/mailbox"
    message = {
      "recipients" => {
        "values" => [
          {
            "person" => {
              "_path" => "/people/#{options[:id]}",
              "first-name" => options[:first_name],
              "last-name" => options[:last_name]
            }
          }]
      },
      "subject" => "Invitation to connect.",
      "body" => options[:body],
      "item-content" => {
        "invitation-request" => {
          "connect-type" => "friend",
          "authorization" => {:"name" => 'NAME_SEARCH',:"value" => 'Mjwh'}
        }
      }
    }
    post(path, MultiJson.dump(message), "Content-Type" => "application/json")
  end
end
```

invite people should be add `"authorization" => {:"name" => 'NAME_SEARCH',:"value" => 'Mjwh'}` from the searched people

`client.search(:fields => [{ :people => %w(id first-name last-name api-standard-profile-request)}],:'first-name' =>  params["first_name"])`

Comment: Looks like this is intended to be a comment to the previous answer. Don't post comments as answers.